# Using MATLAB plots to find linear equation constants

Tags: matlab, plot, linear-algebra

> Finding `m` and `c` for an equation `y = mx + c`, with the help of math and plots.
>   `y` is `data_model_1`, `x` is time.
>   Avoid other MATLAB functions like `fitlm` as it defeats the purpose.

I am having trouble finding the constants `m` and `c`. I am trying to find both `m` and `c` by limiting them to a range (based on smart guess) and I need to deduce the `m` and `c` values based on the mean error range. The point where mean error range is closest to 0 should be my `m` and `c` values.

```
load(file)

figure
plot(time,data_model_1,'bo')
hold on
for a = 0.11:0.01:0.13
  c = -13:0.1:-10
  data_a = a * time + c ;
  plot(time,data_a,'r');
end

figure
hold on
for a = 0.11:0.01:0.13
  c = -13:0.1:-10
  data_a = a * time + c ;
  mean_range = mean(abs(data_a - data_model_1));
  plot(a,mean_range,'b.')
end
```

Comment: You literally need one character to find `m` and `c`, namely [`\ (or 'mldivide')`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html). It's unclear what you mean by trying to solve this with "smart guesses". Also try and separate *plotting* and *calculation* in your mind and your code, they are independent and optimal `m` and `c` exist regardless whether or not you plot them.

Comment: I need to find the values of m and c. The plots and calculations are essential in getting to the values m and c. I need to use mathematics and plots to solve for m and c, nothing else.

Comment: It's almost like you didn't read my comment... you do not need to *plot* do perform the mathematics, and I have linked to documentation for a mathematical function which would solve the fitting problem for you to find m and c

Answer (score 0):

**A quick & dirty approach**

You can quickly get `m` and `c` using [`fminsearch()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fminsearch.html).  In the first example below, the error function is the *sum of squared error* (SSE).  The second example uses the *sum of absolute error*.  The key here is ensuring the error function is convex.

Note that `c = Beta(1)` and `m = Beta(2)`.

Reproducible example (MATLAB code<sup>[1]</sup>):

```
% Generate some example data
N = 50;
X = 2 + 13*random(makedist('Beta',.7,.8),N,1);
Y = 5 + 1.5.*X + randn(N,1);

% Example 1
SSEh =@(Beta) sum((Y - (Beta(1) + (Beta(2).*X))).^2);
Beta0 = [0.5 0.5];   % Initial Guess
[Beta SSE] = fminsearch(SSEh,Beta0)

% Example 2
SAEh =@(Beta) sum(abs(Y-(Beta(1) + Beta(2).*X)));
[Beta SumAbsErr] = fminsearch(SAEh,Beta0)
```

This is a quick & dirty approach that can work for many applications.

@Wolfie's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52705087/using-matlab-plots-to-find-linear-equation-constants/52909499#comment92336872_52705087) directs you to the analytical approach to solve a system of linear equations with the `\` operator or [`mldivide()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html). This is the more correct approach (though it will get a similar answer). One caveat is this approach gets the SSE answer.

<sub>[1] Tested with MATLAB R2018a</sub>